# Atualizar valor de variável com slider no MATLAB

Tags: matlab, slider

**Tenho um arquivo struct:**
    x.head=imread('brain.jpg');
        whos x

**Tenho um slider:**

```
 G3.slide = uicontrol('style','slide',...
                 'unit','pix',...
                 'position',[400 280 120 30],...
                 'min',-10,'max',10,'val',1,...
                 'sliderstep',[1/20 1/10],...
                 'callback',{@sl_call3,G3});
```

**que chama a funçao:**

```
function [] = sl_call(varargin)

% Callback for the slider.
[k,x] = varargin{[1,3]};
set(x.head,x.head*get(k,'value'))
```

Porém quando rodo, tenho o erro:

> **Reference to non-existent field 'head'.
>   Error in Projeto/sl_call (line 87) set(x.head,x.head*get(k,'value'))   Error while evaluating
>   UIControl Callback**